# Field calculator error and Geoprocessing results window empty

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, field-calculator, editing

[image]I need to use the field caculator for a new field that I have just added but I keep getting the following error:

[image]
The problem is that when I open the Geoprocessing Results window is just completly empty, which is so weird, I don't know what to do and I need to use the field calculator to keep going with my work

The field is a short integer and is just equal to another field called OBJECTID

Comment: Are you trying to use special characters in a short integer field?

Comment: is you destination field of the same type as the input field ? What command do you use ?

Comment: What do you mean with special characters? 

I have in my attribute table a default field called OBJECTID so I need to add a new field called: SiteID, which it should be TYPE: Short Integer, after this I need to, Right-click the new SiteID field heading and choose Field Calculator. Once the dialob box of Field Calculator is open, I double click OBJECTID as I want SiteID to be the same value, so [OBJECTID] will appear into the expression box. After clicked OK I got the error

Comment: i like turtles i like turtles i like turtles

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to some possible issues/solutions that might be of help [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s00000025000000)

1)are you in an editing session?

2)is the original OID field you are trying to copy a long integer? make sure the data type of the field you are trying to copy into matches the data type of the OID field.

3)sometimes this error will pop up if the Parser (VB script or Python) and Type (Number,String,Date) are mismatched with what is entered into the expression.

Comment: I have just edited above an Image with the table how it looks right now, the both fields, OBJECTID and ShapeID seems to be short integer so it should be alright...¿? , Jaspar what do you mean when you are asking if I am on a editing session? And also do you guys have any idea why my geoprocessing results window is empty when I open it after the error appears? THANKS A LOT TO ALL!

Comment: From the "Editor" toolbar dropdown, select "start editing" and then try your edits to your attribute table, don't forget to save your edits when you close the edit session. If you don't see your editor toolbar, you may have to turn it on. Simply click the "Customize" tab and select "toolbars" and then select/check on "Editor"

Comment: oK let see if I understood, I turned on the edit tool bar as you said, and I have just edited by hand the 1,2,3,4,5 short integer values for SiteID in the attribute table and then save it in the editor tool bar, instead of doing = [OBJECTID] in the field calculato, this should work?

Comment: After you start an editing session from the editor toolbar, you can then open your attribute table, make your changes to the SiteID field by setting it equal to the OBJECTID in Field Calculator, go back to your Editor toolbar, save your edits and then close edit session. That should do the trick.

Comment: mmm it doesnt work either, because when i go into field calculatr choose [OBJECTID] and then after click OK then error appears again..

Comment: Could it be a permission issue where you would have read only privileges? Is someone else working with this same data layer at the same time (open on another computer)? is the data layer you are working with in a compressed geodatabase? I am not sure why this won't work for you as described above....You should be able to select your SITEID field column, right click to access field calculator, set SITEID= to OBJECTID in the expression box by simply clicking/selecting OBJECTID from your field choices and hit OK.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this error is generated when the two field types are not the same.  For example is calculating an integer field from a string field.